# Simple popup java form with at least two fields

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

When the user clicks a button, I want to show a popup form that should have at least two JTextFields and two JLabels, so using `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` is not a possibility.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should at least consider one of the [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) methods such as `showInputDialog()` or `showMessageDialog()`.

Addendum: The choice to use [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) hinges more on the suitability of modality, rather than on the number of components shown. See also [*How to Make Dialogs*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

Addendum: As noted in a comment by @camickr, you can set the focus to a particular component using the approach discussed in [*Dialog Focus*](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/), cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6478443/230513).

[image]

```
package gui;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3002830/230513 */
class JOptionPaneTest {

    private static void display() {
        String[] items = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"};
        JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<>(items);
        JTextField field1 = new JTextField("1234.56");
        JTextField field2 = new JTextField("9876.54");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.add(combo);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Field 1:"));
        panel.add(field1);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Field 2:"));
        panel.add(field2);
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, "Test",
            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            System.out.println(combo.getSelectedItem()
                + " " + field1.getText()
                + " " + field2.getText());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Cancelled");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the initial confusion between answer and example.

Comment: How can I retrieve the input?

Comment: I've elaborated above and added a link to the tutorial.

Comment: +1, for showing how an option pane can be used for this and for including a link to the tutorial. There is one problem with using a panel this way. Focus will appear on the button, not the text field which may be a problem. For a solution to this check out the "Dialog Focus" link: http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/

Comment: @camickr: Thank you for the link to that very helpful article, which I've cited above. Your considerable experience often anticipates the next likely question. I welcome additions and corrections; please don't hesitate to edit my answers as the opportunity arises.

Comment: I keep forgetting I can edit postings and it is easier to edit the posting to add a link. I'll try an remember the next time :)

Comment: + You will soon earn the swing specialist badge ;-)

Comment: Exactly the same example I had given , though mine is hard, yours is good :-)

Comment: Wow, this is a fantastic example of a quick popup box. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

With the small [UiBooster](https://github.com/Milchreis/UiBooster#form-dialog) library you can build a form dialog in a few lines of code.

```
FilledForm form = new UiBooster()
        .createForm("Personal informations")
        .addText("Whats your first name?")
        .addTextArea("Tell me something about you")
        .addSelection(
                "Whats your favorite movie?",
                Arrays.asList("Pulp Fiction", "Bambi", "The Godfather", "Hangover"))
        .show();
```

[image]