# How to make an input dialogbox which has more than one textfield(ie. can take many inputs)

Tags: java, swing, input, textfield, dialog

I have implemented an **input** DialogBox, however this has **one textfield**. I need an input DialogBox which has **many textfields** to take input from and store each String in an array.

What I have done so far:

[image]

---

### CODE

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class second extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

JLabel enterName;
JTextField name;
JButton click;
String storeName;

public second() {

    setLayout(null);
    setSize(300, 250);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    click = new JButton("Click");
    click.setBounds(100, 190, 60, 30);
    click.addActionListener(this);
    add(click);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == click) {
    String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "What is your name?",
                "Enter your name",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

    second s = new second();
    s.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

---

Many Thanks

Comment: You might look at this [example][1]. [1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002830

Answer (score 2):

Use a JDialog Form.

You can use more than one input fields in it.

You can see examples in this [link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/1220__JDialog.htm).

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is:

```
String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
(null,"<html>Whats your name?"+ "<br>Enter your name:",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
```

The br stands for brake or brake line(basically hitting enter key)
I cant enter the <> cause it brakes the line in comments.