# Creating a JDialog with three related lists

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am an inexperienced Java Swing developer and I need to create a JDialog which displays three different lists of data. The user's selection of an item in the first list will update the content of the second list and the selection of an item in the second list will update the content of the third list. Also when the dialog is launched the first item of all three lists should be selected.

Can someone suggest me an approach to do such a thing? Should I use three or JLists?

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definite tutorial on [`JList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) and its selection listener should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [Geoffrey Zheng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62479/geoffrey-zheng), `JList` is an excellent choice. As an alternative, you might also look at `JComboBox`; there's a two-tier example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191882). Either component can be added to `JOptionPane`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002830).