# How to make a function like JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(xxx,"xxx")?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

It take a full weekend with stressful in trying to make a function that show dialog and could return value after click ok (like JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(xxx,"xxx"))? could anyone help me about writing the code ?

Thanks in advance

Makara

Comment: Why not using the same ?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002787

Comment: Much easier to get help if you show (include in the question) what you have done so far.

Comment: I have a JFrame that show data of database(Ms.Access 2003) in JTable and I have a JDialog that will show if you click sort button(JFrame i wrote in one file and JDialog wrote in other). What I really want is to add the JDialog with JFrame(mdi form), after click button ok of JDialog, JDialog will close and return some SQL String to sort my data in JTable.

Answer (score 4):

Use a JOptionPane.showInputDialog().

Other alternatives are to hand a GUI control(s) to the JOptionPane.showMessageDialog() and query the state of the control(s) once it is closed, or use a JDialog.

If you spend more than 15 minutes trying to get a JOptionPane to do exactly as required, it is a good sign that a JOptionPane is not the class for the job.

Comment: Yeah, I thought on that way too. But the only problem is I don't know to coding ?? Could you show me a simple code ?

Comment: We won't code for you. Get some tutorials and start learning.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a trivial approach. It is a class and not a function. If you want to construct it with just have two parameters, make an additional constructor that has the two parameters you need.

[Here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#ih5hvYJNSIA/src/share/classes/javax/swing/JOptionPane.java&q=lang%3ajava%20class%3aJOptionPane&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc) you can take a look at the real McCoy...

```
public class MyOwnJDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {
    private String theMessage;

    public MyOwnJDialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal, String theMessage) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
        this.theMessage = theMessage;
        jLabel1.setText(theMessage);
        setVisible(true);
    }


    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().add(jLabel1, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        jButton1.setText("OK");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(jButton1);

        getContentPane().add(jPanel1, java.awt.BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        pack();
    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        dispose();
    }

    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Design what classes you will need and what you want the GUI to look like
2. Create a skeleton of the classes and methods and start filling in the details.
3. Create a method that could put this together and return the output.

Some useful items:

- JDialog from API: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html
- How to make dialogs tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html