# How to add to Dialog Boxes in Java (Swing)?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simple popup java form with at least two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002787/simple-popup-java-form-with-at-least-two-fields)

I'm trying to make a Dialog Box that has multiple buttons, places to enter text, etc.  I'm using this tutorial - http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html, but it doesn't have anything about having multiple items.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The first page of that tutorial shows a dialog with radio buttons, tabs and push buttons.  How is that not "having multiple items"?

Comment: The dialog doesn't show up until you press the "Show it" button.  The only dialogs that show up are the simpler ones shown before.

Comment: Here's [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002787/simple-popup-java-form-with-at-least-two-fields/3002830#3002830) with even more items, but you have to run it to see them. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Many of the showXXXXDialog methods take an Object as one of the arguments.  If that Object is a String, it will display a String.  If that Object is a Container containing buttons, input fields and other widgets, it will display that.

To quote http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html

> ```
> Parameters:
> The parameters to these methods follow consistent patterns:
>
>
> parentComponent
> ```
>
> Defines the Component that is to be the parent of this dialog box. It
>   is used in two ways: the Frame that
>   contains it is used as the Frame
>   parent for the dialog box, and its
>   screen coordinates are used in the
>   placement of the dialog box. In
>   general, the dialog box is placed just
>   below the component. This parameter
>   may be null, in which case a default
>   Frame is used as the parent, and the
>   dialog will be centered on the screen
>   (depending on the L&F).
>
> ```
> message
> ```
>
> A descriptive message to be placed in the dialog box. In the most common
>   usage, message is just a String or
>   String constant. However, the type of
>   this parameter is actually Object. Its
>   interpretation depends on its type:
>
> Object[]
>   An array of objects is interpreted as a series of messages (one per
>   object) arranged in a vertical stack.
>   The interpretation is recursive --
>   each object in the array is
>   interpreted according to its type.
>
> Component
>   The Component is displayed in the dialog.
>
> Icon
>   The Icon is wrapped in a JLabel and displayed in the dialog.
>
> others
>   The object is converted to a String by calling its toString method. The result is wrapped in a JLabel and displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here. 
Either go and use JOptionPane methods to show a dialog as detailed by `Paul Tomblin` or build your own dialog.

The second option is a necessity if you are after a fine grained control of a dialog, e.g. if you need different names (this can be done also by use of JOptionPane.showOptionDialog) or location of buttons on the dialog, or if you need a not modal dialog.

**Simple Example:**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DialogsTest
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {               
                JPanel p = new JPanel();
                JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
                contentPane.add(p);
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setContentPane(contentPane);
                f.setSize(400, 300);
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setVisible(true);         
                /* 
                 * NOTE: It is not recomended to share the same instance of a component 
                 * by different parents. Thought it is fine here since the first 
                 * dialog will release it before the second will get it.
                 * But in a situation when we wouldn't make the 'dialog' modal and 
                 * we would show it after the 'option pane dialog' it would be empty.
                 */
                JPanel message = new JPanel();
                message.add(new JLabel("Label:"));              
                message.add(new JTextField("ABCD"));
                message.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(f, message, "Default made dialog", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

                Object[] options = new String[]{"a", "b", "c"};
                JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(f, message, "", JOptionPane.YES_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, 
                        null, options, options[0]);
                JDialog dialog = new JDialog(f, "Custom made dialog");
                dialog.setModal(true);
                dialog.setContentPane(message);
                dialog.pack();
                dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(f);
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

BTW you have a very nice (maybe too rich) example in the Java tutorial you read.