# validate jtextfield in two different class use keylistener

Tags: java, swing

I created a `classA` for designing process and `classB` for creating methods; that method is used to call a `classA` `JTextField`. `JtextField1` is used to update only uppercase `String`, `JTextField2` is used to update only numeric values; `Jtextfield3` is used to update email ID format. I am getting an error when I am calling from another class. I can't to call that `ClassB` method in `ClassA` `JTextField`.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class sample {

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("name");
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("reg.no");
    JTextField text1 = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField text2 = new JTextField(10);
    JFrame fr = new JFrame();

    public sample() {
        JPanel jp = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        KeyListener textkey = new textListener();
        text1.addKeyListener(textkey);//created a keylistener for text1
        text2.addKeyListener(textkey);//created a keylistener for text2
        jp.add(label1);
        jp.add(text1);
        jp.add(label2);
        jp.add(text2);
        fr.add(jp);
        fr.pack();
        fr.setSize(430, 350);
        fr.setTitle("form1");
        fr.setVisible(true);
    }

    class textListener implements KeyListener {//keyListener is implemented

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel();
            String value = text1.getText();
            String value1 = text2.getText();
            String keyString;
            int l = value.length();
            if ((e.getKeyCode() >= KeyEvent.VK_A
                && e.getKeyCode() <= KeyEvent.VK_Z)
                || (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)
                || (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK)) {
                text1.setEditable(true);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(label, "Enter Alpha",
                    "InputError", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String ar[]) {
        new sample();
    }
}
```

Comment: please show us your code and error

Comment: Are these fields private? As Ran said, we need to see more.

Comment: I am just editted my code, give me a reply soon

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: Have a look at [my answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7454211/544963). Change whatever needs to be changed accordingly.