# Running a shell script from JFrame using user input (Swing)

Tags: java, swing, bash, jbutton, jdialog

Firstly I should say that the Java application, once created, will be run on a raspberry pi so will have access to Unix X terminal in order to run shell scripts.

I have a swing JDialog with a text box and a button. The button currently opens the results JDialog, I just now have to try and figure out the workings to get a result.

The user will input a hostname into the text box, then click the button.

On click of the button I need to execute a bash shell in unix; I have the path I'll just need to append this path with "/multiping single hostname". I should say that multiping runs a script with cases whereby single pings a single host.

I then need to read the results of an output file and pass them to the results JDialog.

I am a novice with Java unfortunately and am using netbeans which isnt the most fun I've ever had, but any pointers or help or anything would be really well received.

Answer (score 1):

You can access your dialog's content, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10067256/230513). You can invoke `ping` using `ProcessBuilder`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5740673/230513). To avoid blocking the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), use a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) to `publish()` interim results from the background thread and update your GUI in `process()`.