# How to constrain JFileChooser to select particular number files?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

Using `JFileChooser`, I have enabled multi-selection mode by `setMultiSelectionEnabled(true)`, but how can I set a limit so that the user can only select a particular number of text (or other) files?

```
public File[] fileSelect() {
    fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileNameExtFilter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Text File","txt");
    fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
    fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Open Question Set");
    fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
    fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    fileChooser.setFileFilter(fileNameExtFilter);
    fileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);

    if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        return fileChooser.getSelectedFiles();
    else
        return null;
}
```

Comment: *"..but how to put limit on that so that user can only pick three files."*  Why only 3?  If that were the case, I'd offer the user a single selection file chooser, 3 times.

Comment: I have to send path of those files to other class's constructor so can't do looping I guess.And "only 3" is in my case.I agree with you, I should ask in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several approaches are possible:

- Create a custom [`FileChooserUI`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/FileChooserUI.html) by subclassing `BasicFileChooserUI` and limit the selection in your implementation of the nested class `SelectionListener`.
- Create a custom file browser, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15150756/230513), and limit the selection in the relevant listener.
- Use the existing `FileChooser` and present a dialog when the selection exceeds three; consider using a `JTable` containing checkboxes as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528604/230513).
- Use separate chooser panels, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10067256/230513) for two files via `createPathPanel()`.

[image]

The best choice and exact details will depend on the use case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found 1,3 & 4 suitable to my situation.

Comment: Any example of how to implement number 1 ?

Comment: I'd start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswing%5D+extends+BasicFileChooserUI) and consider [ask].