# How to fix deselection behavior of limited selection JFileChooser.setSelectedFiles(fs) in PropertyChangeListener to maintain already selected files?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, propertychangelistener, deselect

I have `JFileChooser.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener());` where `PropertyChangeListener` listens to the changes of the count size of files selection, so that it limits the count of selection to a specified count of files. It works well, but a little flaw in the behavior of selection/deselection of files.

Say I limit selection count size to be 3, then I select any 3 files, after that when I select one more file ***below*** that 3 selected files (below in position), the new selection will be rejected (deselected) but maintain the already 3 selected files; **which is the expected behavior**. However, oppositely; when I select one more file ***above*** any of the already 3 selected files (above in position), that new selected file will be selected causing deselection to the one file at the bottom of the already 3 selected files.

I need to maintain the deselection behavior after selecting ***above*** file to be the same as after selecting ***below*** file.

Here is [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FileChooserWithLimitedFilesSelection {

    private JPanel panel;
    private JFileChooser fileChooser;
    private JButton btnFileChooser;

    public FileChooserWithLimitedFilesSelection() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        btnFileChooser = new JButton("Browse...");
        btnFileChooser.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
        panel.add(btnFileChooser);
    }

    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (fileChooser == null) {
                fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                fileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
                fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
                fileChooser.addPropertyChangeListener(new LimitSelectionHandler());
            }
            int returnedValue = fileChooser.showDialog(null, "Select files");
            // 
        }
    }

    private class LimitSelectionHandler implements PropertyChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            File[] selectedFiles = fileChooser.getSelectedFiles();
            int currentSelectionLength = selectedFiles.length;
            if (currentSelectionLength > 3) {
                File[] limitedFilesSelection = new File[3];
                for (int i = 0; i < limitedFilesSelection.length; i++) {
                    limitedFilesSelection[i] = selectedFiles[i];
                }
                fileChooser.setSelectedFiles(limitedFilesSelection);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(fileChooser, "Only 3 selected files allowed.", "File chooser",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            FileChooserWithLimitedFilesSelection fcwrfs = new FileChooserWithLimitedFilesSelection();
            frame.add(fcwrfs.panel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

I took the implementation code of `PropertyChangeListener` from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55883983/6811102).

Comment: [`getSelectedFiles()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getSelectedFiles()) does not specify any order for the returned files. The observed behavior is consistent with files returned in the same order as shown in the list. However, your current approach could pick any 3 files. If you want to keep previously selected, you have to remember which files were previously selected.

Comment: _"you have to remember which files were previously selected"_  Yes, that is the point, how can I get references to those previously selected files, so that I keep them selected.

Comment: You store the current selected files somewhere and the next time your listener is invoked, those stored files are the previous one.

Comment: @Holger +1 Thanks. Sometimes I think it is a rocket science problem such that it drives me to overthink out the box ignoring the box itself such that I need someone to just turn my head to look inside the box.

Answer (score 1):

It is just as simple as [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) has [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77913661/how-to-fix-deselection-behavior-of-limited-selection-jfilechooser-setselectedfil?noredirect=1#comment137361027_77913661) to the question above.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FileChooserWithLimitedFilesSelection {

    private JPanel panel;
    private JFileChooser fileChooser;
    private JButton btnFileChooser;
    private File[] limitedFilesSelection;

    public FileChooserWithLimitedFilesSelection() {
        limitedFilesSelection = new File[3];
        panel = new JPanel();
        btnFileChooser = new JButton("Browse...");
        btnFileChooser.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
        panel.add(btnFileChooser);
    }

    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (fileChooser == null) {
                fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                fileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
                fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
                fileChooser.addPropertyChangeListener(new LimitSelectionHandler());
            }
            int returnedValue = fileChooser.showDialog(null, "Select files");
            // 
        }
    }

    private class LimitSelectionHandler implements PropertyChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            File[] selectedFiles = fileChooser.getSelectedFiles();
            int currentSelectionLength = selectedFiles.length;
            if (currentSelectionLength == 3) {
                for (int i = 0; i < limitedFilesSelection.length; i++) {
                    limitedFilesSelection[i] = selectedFiles[i];
                }
            } else if (currentSelectionLength > 3) {
                fileChooser.setSelectedFiles(limitedFilesSelection);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(fileChooser, "Only 3 selected files allowed.", "File chooser",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            FileChooserWithLimitedFilesSelection fcwrfs = new FileChooserWithLimitedFilesSelection();
            frame.add(fcwrfs.panel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```