# i want to copy a source file in a destination file but how to choose the full path of a file in textfield by choosefiler and put it in this code

Tags: java, swing

I want to copy a source file in a destination file,knowing that those two files have to be chosen by a choosefiler and past it in a textfield to see the fullpath so how to choose the full path of a file in textfield by choosefiler and put it in this code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      FileInputStream fis = null;
      FileOutputStream fos = null;

      try {

         fis = new FileInputStream(new File(""));
         fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(""));

         byte[] buf = new byte[8];

         int n = 0;

         while ((n = fis.read(buf)) >= 0) {

            for (byte bit : buf) {
               System.out.print("\t" + bit + "(" + (char) bit + ")");
               System.out.println("");
            }

            buf = new byte[8];

         }
         System.out.println("Copie terminée !");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {

         e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {


         try {
            if (fis != null)
               fis.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }

         try {
            if (fos != null)
               fos.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your question correctly, before you click on *"Post your question"*.

Comment: Move the functionality from `main` into `copier`; in your `actionPerformed` method make a instance of `Applicationdecopie` and call it's `copier` method

Comment: thank you for answering me but it didn't work

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: You might be able to leverage this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10067256/230513).