# Java: Multiple lines of text using JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Text");

Tags: java, swing, text, joptionpane

I need a text pop up like the one you get with `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Text");` Just with multiple lines, like...

```
I'm new to java.
I have no background in programming.
I could use some help
```

How would I do this?

Comment: See also [`JOptionPaneTest`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3002830/230513).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011492/text-wrap-in-joptionpane (in particular the accepted answer there).

Answer (score 18):

You could use '\n' like so:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello\nworld");
```

Comment: -1 He wants to get an input text from the user (with the input dialog looking like a text area), not output multiple lines to the user.

Answer (score 17):

There's probably a dozen other ways to do this, but the simplest I can think of is

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html>I'm new to java.<br>I have no background in programming.<br>I could use some help Thanks!</html>");
```

Another approach to demonstrate the power of the `JOptionPane`

```
JTextArea msg = new JTextArea("This is a really silly example of what can be achieved with a JOptionPane, but this is going to excese for what you have asked for");
msg.setLineWrap(true);
msg.setWrapStyleWord(true);

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(msg);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, scrollPane);
```

Comment: @DavidKroukamp Love HTML in Java, just wish it had better CSS support

Comment: Have you had  peek at [Skinning JavaFX Applications with CSS](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm) and you can [style layouts using CSS in JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/style_css.htm)

Comment: IS there a difference between this and using /n? or is it personal preference? ...Disregard this post...

Comment: @jjd712 Given the requirements, David's solutions is simpler.  If you wanted to display a more complex message (such as images or tabular data), then this would be more useful.  I use a similar approach when I want to display complex tooltips. Check update for a even more complex, but viable, solution

Comment: *"wish it had better CSS support"*  .. `<html>I'm new to java.<br>`  Not really relevant to this question (where the OP seems to know where they want line breaks) but at least the J2SE supports the CSS `width` attribute if added to the `body` element.  That can help us avoid having to figure out were to put line breaks in multiline text.  :)