# How do I show an auto vertical scrollbar with JOptionPane and showMessage Dialog?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, joptionpane, jscrollbar

I have a QuizApplication which will show up the results upon user finished the test.
I have following piece of code which returns quiz result as string:

```
public String getResult() {
 int score = 0;
    String[] choices;
    String scoreB = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
        if (test[i].getCorrect() == test[i].getAns()) {
            score++;
        } else {
          choices = test[i].getChoice();
            scoreB += "Question " + (i + 1) + " : " + test[i].getQn() + "\n<html></br>choices[test[i].getCorrect() - 1] + "\n\n";
        }
    } // end of for loop
      return result;
}
```

And then I want to show the result in the form of MessageDialog, so I used:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, newQuiz.getResult()
```

But, I want to add a vertical scrollbar onto the `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

One of the parameters to [`showMessageDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29) is an `Object`.  If this `Object` is a `Component`, it will be added to the dialog's view.

I'm not sure why you want to add `JScrollBar` to the dialog, but you will need to construct a `Component` containing all the elements you want to display and pass it to the dialog via the message parameter.

Check out [How to use Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#features) for details

Answer (score 1):

As a concrete example of @MadProgrammer's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15105492/230513), this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14011536/230513) wraps a `JTextArea` in a `JScrollPane` and passes the latter to `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()`. Also consider this [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14011645/230513) using HTML/CSS.

[image]

Comment: Hi trashgod, I have seen many JTextArea example and it is no good to what I want to achieve.  For the JTextArea, you will specify an area like JtextArea output = new JTextArea(200, 200) like this, but I want a dynamic "dialog box" or frame to display my answers and it can exceed a screen size.  So, a vertical scrollbar is necessary for a user to see all the answers.

Comment: Why not a resizable `JDialog` instead of a `JOptionPane`?