# How can I output all values of an array in a single JOptionPane method?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jlabel, joptionpane

I want to output all the values in a variable in the same sentence in a showMessageDialog method, I know I could use a JList to put them all in one screen, but I'd rather have something like: 3,4,2,62,12,41,5

I could do something like

```
 for(int x = 0;x < array.length;x++){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,array[x] + ",");}
```

But that would take more than one screen and it's not what I want.

Also, perhaps it could be done with a JLabel instead, I'll suit myself with that if it's easier.

Comment: Could you not build the string first then call `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog`?

Comment: Concatenate all string using `StringBuilder` and then show the resulting `String`

Answer (score 1):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14011536/230513), use `StringBuilder` to construct a line-oriented representation of your array and display it in a `JScrollPane` in a `JOptionPane`. The scroll pane's preferred size can be arbitrary.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do the concatenation first:

```
String s = Arrays.toString(array);
s = s.substring(1,s.length-1);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,s);
```

Comment: @GuillaumePolet, Corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is, if the array is sufficiently large, then it will not fit on the screen anyway. Presenting it in a messagebox may not be usefull to the user.

If you need to show this in a manageable way for arbitrary large arrays, then I would rather write a small dialog class, which is not much work, and then use a scrollable textarea instead.

This way you can prepare it in any way you want to. However, from your short sample it's not entirely clear if you always have a small number of items, in which case creating the string should be sufficient.