# Add a line at a time to a String

Tags: java, swing, file-io, java.util.scanner, jtextarea

I have this program that lets you open a file and it reads it in to a `JTextArea` all at once using the following code:

```
 try{
    String fileContents = new Scanner(new File(fileName)).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
  }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }

  myTextArea.setText(fileContents);
```

and this works. But my question is how can I read this into my `fileContents` string and still have it add in the line breaks every time I get a new-line character?

Here is what I have, but this puts it all in one line in my textArea:

```
 try{
Scanner contentsTextFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
while(contentsTextFile.hasNext()){
    fileContents = contentsTextFile.useDelimiter("\r\n|\n").nextLine(); 
    }

}catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

   myTextArea.setText(fileContents);
```

What I would like to see is this line of text get a new line using a delimiter that only reads one line at a time instead of the entire file.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read a file line-by-line using a `BufferedReader` and use the `append()` method of `JTextArea` for each line read. For convenience, wrap the `JTextArea` in a suitably sized `JScrollPane`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14011536/230513). If you anticipate any latency, use a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) to read in the background, and call `append()` in `process()`.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
String s;
while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
    myTextArea.append(s + "\n");
}
```

Comment: yeah this is what i decided i would do. I get the file contents using the `FileReader` and `BufferedReader` then i append them one at a time to the `JTextArea` using `myTextArea.append(contents);`

Comment: +1 but JTextComponent.read/write accepting separators in file (both directions I/O)

Comment: @mKorbel: Agree for undivided operation on `Document`. Anything but `Scanner`! :-)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use [`JTextComponent.read(Reader,Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29) which:

> Initializes from a stream. This creates a model of the type appropriate for the component and initializes the model from the stream. By default this will load the model as plain text. Previous contents of the model are discarded.

Comment: I am not sure i understand what you are telling me. Can't i just read a line into a string at a time and concatenate it onto what the string already contains and supply each new concatenation with a newline character?

Comment: Try it and see what it does.

Comment: Let me try this and i will get back to you. Thanks in advance

Comment: Also consider the `append()` method of `JTextArea`.