# How to print exception in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, exception, jtextpane, redirect

```
doc = (StyledDocument) textPane.getDocument();
err = textPaneError.getStyledDocument();
try {
    textPane.setText("\b");
    doc.insertString(textPane.getCaretPosition(), (String) stack.pop(), styleT);
    doc.insertString(textPane.getCaretPosition()-1, "\n", styleB);
} catch (BadLocationException e1) {
    try {
        err.insertString(0, "There is no opened tag", styleR);
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am trying to print all the exception in a JTextPane. This is my code, it doesn't work. Can somebody told me where is the problem? 
Thanks

Comment: This [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14011536/230513) uses `JTextArea`.

Answer (score 0):

```
package printexception;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

public class PrintException extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new PrintException().setVisible(true);            }
            }
        );
    }

    private final JTextPane text = new JTextPane();

    public PrintException() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 300);

        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar();
        toolbar.add(new CreateException());

        getContentPane().add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(text));
    }

    private class CreateException extends AbstractAction {

        CreateException() {
            putValue(NAME, "Print Exception");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            Exception ex = new Exception();

            AttributeSet attr = null;
            StyledDocument doc = text.getStyledDocument();

            for (StackTraceElement trace : ex.getStackTrace()) {
                try {
                    doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), trace.toString() + '\n', attr);
                } catch (BadLocationException ex1) {
                    ex1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```