# How to resize JScrollPane itself (not viewport) programmatically?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I want to resize JScrollPane programmatically. I do not want to resize viewport of JScrollPane but JScrollPane itself together with parent JDialog.

So far I tried to setPreferredSize of JScrollPane and revalidate it but it does not work.
Here is my code that creates JScrollPane and adds it into JDialog.

```
public ConnectionTreeTooltip(MainFrame parent) {
        super(parent, "", false);
        super.setUndecorated(true);
        JPanel contentPane = (JPanel) super.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED, Color.blue, Color.red));
        tipLabel = new JLabel();
        tipLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tipLabel);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 3, 1, 1));
     // super.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        super.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        super.pack();
    }
```

So I have my JScrollPane created all right and its viewport is automatically resized whenever text of JLabel changes.

How to resize JScrollPane itself together with parent JDialog?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved already!

I only had to call pack() method on JDialog after I set preferredSize of JScrollPane. Like so:

```
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(tempLabel.getPreferredSize());
super.pack();
```

Comment: Instead, override `getPreferredSize()`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14011536/230513).