# How to run ANTLR GUI in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, antlr4, abstract-syntax-tree, antlrworks

```
ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(System.in);
CLexer lexer = new CLexer(input);           
CommonTokenStream tokens=new CommonTokenStream(lexer); 
CParser parser = new CParser(tokens); 
ParseTree tree=parser.translationUnit(0);
System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser));
```

I already got the AST from ANTLR, I want to have a look at the AST in the GUI way. But how to do that in java swing? thank you guys.

Comment: Try the approach shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14011536/230513).

Answer (score 0):

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setContentPane( new JScrollPane( new TreeViewer( null, tree ) ) );
frame.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 800, 600 ) );
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
frame.setVisible( true );
```