# Is it possible to set length of paragraph in JTextPane StyledDocument?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, styleddocument

I am using `JTextPane` with `StyledDocument`, is it possible to set length of its paragraph?
My goal is when the length of text which is inserted in the `JTextPane` is longer than 400px, exceed go to new line.

Edit:

I use method below to set style for textPane

```
public Style getstyle(String message){
    Style style = context.addStyle("mystyle", null);
    StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.GRAY);
    StyleConstants.setBackground(style, new Color(162, 234, 167));
    SimpleAttributeSet mystyle = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    StyleConstants.setFontFamily(style, "SansSerif");
    document.setParagraphAttributes(document.getLength(), message.length(), mystyle, false);
    return style;
}
```

and use following to insert text to my JTextPane:

```
try {
    document.insertString(document.getLength(), " "+message+"\n", getStyle(message));
} catch (BadLocationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want to set length of paragraph.

Edit2:

I use different style, for different type of my text.

Edit3:

I add my `JTextPane` to `JPanel` with scrollbar.

```
context = new StyleContext();
document = new DefaultStyledDocument(context);
Pane = new JTextPane(document);
Pane.setEditable(false);

Panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(Panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(Pane);
Panel.add(scroll , BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: If the `StyledDocument` happens to be HTML, the width of the document can be suggested by the CSS used.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14011645/418556) for how to do it with an HTML formatted `JLabel`.

Comment: It is text, how can I set ot to text/html?

Comment: Post your code. The same you were asked in your previous questions. You were provided with several different approaches. Show us your best attempt.

Comment: @ StanislavL I edit my question and post my code

Comment: Nothing in your code prevents setting JTextPane's width to be 400px

Comment: @ StanislavL. Sorry, I should say that : I add my JTextPane to JPanel with scrollbar. I edit my question again!

Comment: BorderLayout does not care about size. It just enlarge the scroll to fill all available width. Try to use another LayoutManager

Comment: @ StanislavL, which layout do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
    pane.setContentType("text/html");
    final JFrame frm = new JFrame("Text editor");
    pane.setText("<html><table><tr><td width=\"400\"></td></tr></table</html>");
    frm.add(new JScrollPane(pane));
    frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frm.setSize(500, 500);
    frm.setVisible(true);
}
```

Your text will go to new line after 400px

Comment: If I set StyledDocument to be HTML, I couldn't use my style which I define for each type of my text.

Comment: @user90 You can define your style using HTML notation.

Comment: `<td width=\"400\">..`  400 what?  Characters, pixels, ..?

Comment: @Sergiy Medvynskyy also I add some component to my JTextPane which their alignment should set to right or left depends on their type. How can I set their alignment by set content type to html?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I think px is default.

Comment: Nope.  According the the W3C a width is either `px` or `em` or a `%` (or invalid).  And we should not trust 'defaults' in the Swing toolkit.  E.G. `JFrame` used to default to `FlowLayout`.  That really stuffed up a lot of apps. when Sun decided to ***change*** the default layout to **`BorderLayout`**.

Comment: appearance of css style is different in JTextPane. (color, alignment). how can I set diffrent alignment?