# GUI does not show if the program ended successfully or there are errors

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am creating a GUI right now. The only issue I have is that when there is a runtime error, the GUI does not stop and it won't let the user know about the error. I cannot have the GUI to stop and give an error message. Is there a syntax or a method that I can use to let the user know if the program ended successfully or there were some errors and it stopped?

thank you!

Comment: Will a [JOptionPane Error Dialog](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DisplayerrormessagedialogwithJOptionPaneERRORMESSAGE.htm) work? You can use it in the `catch` block when you get an Exception to provide the visual feedback.

Comment: `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` can be used to catch some exceptions and then tell something to the user.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14011536/230513).