# Displaying multiple System.out.print's in a single JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, loops, joptionpane

I just started learning Java a couple weeks ago so i'm fairly new. I'm currently working on a TicTacToe game and I was just about finished but instead of having my board display itself as a System.out.print I would like it to be displayed on a JOptionPane message instead to improve it aesthetically. However my board is completely made with loops and i'm not sure how I can display that on a JOptionPane :( I've tried researching similar situations online but I everything I find is quite confusing or doesn't seem to apply to the kind of statements i'm printing. If anyone could help me out it would be much appreciated.

```
public static void showBoard(char[][] brd)
{

    int numRow = brd.length;
    int numCol = brd[0].length;


    System.out.println();

    // This is the column
    System.out.print("    ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numCol; i++)
      System.out.print(i + "   ");
    System.out.print('\n');

    System.out.println(); // blank line after the header

    // The write the table
    for (int i = 0; i < numRow; i++) {
      System.out.print(i + "  ");
      for (int j = 0; j < numCol; j++) {
        if (j != 0)
          System.out.print("|");
        System.out.print(" " + brd[i][j] + " ");
      }

      System.out.println();

      if (i != (numRow - 1)) {
        // separator line
        System.out.print("   ");
        for (int j = 0; j < numCol; j++) {
          if (j != 0)
            System.out.print("+");
          System.out.print("---");
        }

        System.out.println();
      }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: I don't think `JOptionPane` is really what you're after.  Take a look at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for how to build a user interface

Comment: Use `StringBuilder`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14011536/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like MadProgrammer mentioned above, JOptionPane isn't the best way to go about displaying something like this. But if you really want to use JOptionPane, do something like this:

Create a `String` object holding an empty string at the top...

```
String str = "";
```

And replace each of your `System.out.print` statements with `str +=`, followed by whatever was previously contained within the parentheses. For example:

```
str += "    ";
for (int i = 0; i < numCol; i++)
  str += i + "   ";
str += "\n";
```

Replace your `System.out.println` statements with `str += "\n";`.

Finally, at the end you can use `JOptionPane` to display the string.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,str);
```

There are going to be some alignment issues that you'll have to solve on your own since JOptionPane does not place the characters in a gridded alignment like consoles do (as far as I know, at least), but this should give you a good idea of how to do it.

Comment: Thank you sooooooooooooooooooooo much TNT! Your helpfulness is over 9000. Got my program running properly (finally!) :D