# Setting underlined text to textarea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, underline

I am having `StringBuffer` which is set to `JTextArea`. Now I want part of the string in `StringBuffer` to be underlined based on some condition how to do that?

Lets say I need to display like Buy Apple at price 4.00 but with text Apple underlined.

Comment: A `JTextArea` supports plain text which means a single font (face, style and size).  To do parts of text in different styles, we need to use a component like a `JLabel` or (closer to a `JTextArea`) a `JEditorPane`.

Comment: But In my application i need the text to be word wrapped. JLabel doesnt support word wrapping. How about JEditorPane?

Comment: *"How about JEditorPane?"*  Well.. how about it?  What are you asking?  BTW - Note that [`JLabel` (when showing HTML) **can** word wrap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14011645/418556).

Comment: I mean if we can do wrapping in JEditorPane. Yes I agree we can do wrapping using JLabel but my text will dynamically change based on the value from other components. in that case i can not use HTML tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JTextPane`. It supports word wrapping by default and you can set the attributes of any piece of text.

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
textPane.setText( "one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\nfive\nsix\nseven\neight" );
StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();

//  Define a keyword attribute

SimpleAttributeSet keyWord = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setForeground(keyWord, Color.RED);
StyleConstants.setBackground(keyWord, Color.YELLOW);
StyleConstants.setUnderline(keyWord, Boolean.TRUE );
StyleConstants.setBold(keyWord, true);

//  Change attributes on some text

doc.setCharacterAttributes(20, 4, keyWord, false);

//  Add some text

try
{
    doc.insertString(0, "Start of text\n", keyWord );
}
catch(Exception e) {}
```

You can also create Actions to change the attributes of any selected text. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for more information and working examples.