# Java: trying to open a text file with a right-click on JTable popup

Tags: java, swing, text, popup, jtable

I'm having a hard time getting a text file to open up when I right click on a row in my `JTable`. I'm currently using `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` to show the text file but it's not working.

The error's I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.appendNull(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
at RowPopup$1.actionPerformed(JtableTest.java:183)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class JtableTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new JtableTest ().createUI();
        }
    };

    EventQueue.invokeLater(r);
}

void createUI() {

    try {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        
        JTable table = new JTable();

        String readLine = null;

      
        File file = new File ("JtableTestDB.txt");

        FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(reader);//Need to close this

        List<Dentry> dataList = new ArrayList<Dentry>();
        while ((readLine = bufReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splitData = readLine.split(";");

            Dentry dentry = new Dentry();
            dentry.setName(splitData[0]);
            dentry.setNumbers(Arrays.copyOfRange(splitData, 1, splitData.length));
            dataList.add(dentry);
        }

        DatabaseTableModel tableModel = new DatabaseTableModel();
        tableModel.setList(dataList);////////////
        table.setModel(tableModel);
    
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.setTitle("File to JTable");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        final RowPopup pop=new RowPopup(table);
        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me)
            
            {
                //determine if right clicked
                if(SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(me))
                {
                    pop.show(me.getComponent(), me.getX(), me.getY());
                }
            }
        });
    } catch(IOException ex) {}
}

class Dentry {

    private String name;
    private String[] number;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNumber(int index) {
        String value = null;
        if (index >= 0 && index < number.length) {
            value = number[index];
        }
        return value;
    }

    public void setNumbers(String... number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}

class DatabaseTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    
    private List<Dentry> list = new ArrayList<Dentry>();
    private String[] columnNames = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"};

    public void setList(List<Dentry> list) {
        this.list = list;
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return columnNames[column];
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return list.get(rowIndex).getName();

         
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
            case 6:                 
                return list.get(rowIndex).getNumber(columnIndex - 1);//return list.get(rowIndex).getNumber(columnIndex);

            default:
                return null;

        }
    }
}
    }
//public class PopupInRows extends JFrame {
//  public PopupInrows()

class RowPopup extends JPopupMenu {
 public RowPopup(JTable table) {
    JMenuItem view=new JMenuItem("View all Moves");
    
    //When View is clicked
    view.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(view, "View");
            try
            { 
            String filetext="",filecontent="";

            File file=new File("JtableTestDB2.txt");
            FileReader fr=new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            while(fr !=null)
            {
                   filetext=br.readLine();
                   sb.append(filetext);
                   sb.append("\n");
            }
            filecontent=sb.toString();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File is"+filecontent);

            }
            catch(Exception ex){}
        }
    });
    //Add Items to Popup
    add(view);
    //add(new Jseparator()); //this would make a line and sep 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the predicate, `fr != null`. Because `fr` is not `null`, the loop never ends until memory is exhausted. Instead, check `filetext`, which will be `null` "if the end of the stream has been reached."

> Is there anyway to have it not display `null` after the text?

Yes, use the same idiom that was used when reading the `TableModel`.

```
while ((filetext = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(filetext);
    sb.append("\n");
}
```

As an aside, do not throw away exceptions; log them or at least print them.

```
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

Instead of a `MouseListener`, consider [`TablePopupEditor`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3591230/230513) as a `CellEditor`.

> Is there a limit on how many characters the message box can show?

Instead of a limit, use scrolling, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14011536/230513).

[image: [image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBAEe.png)

Comment: See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25526869/230513) using `SwingWorker`.

Comment: Thanks trashgod, I changed that line like you said but the file still doesn't come up.. Just a message box that says "null".

Comment: That's great! Thanks trashgod! Is there anyway to have it not display 'null' after the text? and is there a limit on how many characters the message box can show?

Comment: Good questions; I've elaborated above.

Comment: Great! Thanks Trashgod!