# Is there any built-in way to print styled text in Java?

Tags: java, swing, text, graphics, richtext

By styled, I mean a text whose different parts have different formattings like in Wordpad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing supports HTML 3.2 in rendering.
So the code for a simple unstyled label will be:

```
JLabel lblUnstyled = new JLabel();
lblUnstyled.setText("Normal unstyled text");
```

If you want to style your text, you can use HTML 3.2 markup for styling information, so for example:

```
JLabel lblStyled = new JLabel();
lblStyled.setText("<html><head></head><body>This is text with <i>something in italic</i>.</body></html>");
```

Comment: *"Swing supports HTML 3.2 in rendering."* It also supports basic CSS as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011492/text-wrap-in-joptionpane/14011645#14011645) (used for the body width). See also [How to Use HTML in Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html). Swing components that support HTML rendering include `JLabel`, `JButton` (with a few quirks), `JEditorPane`, `JTextPane` ..

Answer (score 0):

Consider looking at JEditorPane which allows displaying different kinds of content. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html

Obviously, you will need to look at a Swing tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `JTextPane`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for more information and working examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/legendmohe/StyleLabel, which extract from jide-oss (http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/swing/StyledLabel.html)

> StyledLabel is a special JLabel which can display text in different
> styles. It is a component between JLabel and JTextPane. JLabel is
> simple, fast but has limited features. For example, you can't use
> different color to draw the text. You may argue JLabel can use HTML
> tag to display text in different colors. However there are two main
> reasons to use StyledLabel. First of all, StyledLabel is very fast and
> almost as fast as JLabel with plain text. HTML JLabel is very slow.