# JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog with a JScrollPane and a maximum size

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I was trying to make a JFrame with a JScrollPane containing hundreds of JRadioButtons and two JButtons below (OK and Cancel). Finally I discovered the JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(...) method.

It seems to be perfect for what I want : From a first JFrame, open a "window" with a Scroll containing my radio buttons and get the selected one in my first JFrame when I click on "OK".
However, when the showConfirmDialog appears, there is no JScrollPane, and we cannot see the bottom of the window (there are hundreds of radio buttons). So :

- I tried to call JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(myScrollPane) instead of adding the JScrollPane to a JPanel and call the method with a JPanel... it didn't work
- I tried to initialize a JOptionPane object, then set its maximum size, then call the method showConfirmDialog with the initialized object but it doesn't work because "the method must be called in a static way".

So I need your help, here is my code, and I don't understand what is wrong and why I don't have a scroll with my radio buttons in the confirm dialog.

```
public void buildMambaJobPathWindow(ArrayList<String> list) {
    ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        JRadioButton radioButton = new JRadioButton(list.get(i));
        buttonGroup.add(radioButton);
        radioButton.addActionListener(this);
        radioButton.setActionCommand(list.get(i));
        radioPanel.add(radioButton);
    }

    JScrollPane myScrollPane = new JScrollPane(radioPanel);         
    myScrollPane.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(600,600));

    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myScrollPane);
}

// Listens to the radio buttons
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String result = e.getActionCommand();
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14011536/230513), you can override the scroll pane's `getPreferredSize()` method to establish the desired size. If the content is larger in either dimension, the corresponding scroll bar will appear as needed.

```
JScrollPane myScrollPane = new JScrollPane(radioPanel){
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(600, 600);
    }
};
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myScrollPane);
```

Comment: Great @trashgod ! It is exactly what I needed, as simple as it is ! :) Have a nice day, thank you.