# How to build a dynamic graphic with JFreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

Actually im trying this:

```
public static DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();;

    public void atualizaDataset(int humano, int zumbi, int rodada){
        final String series1 = "Humano";
        final String series2 = "Zumbi";

        dataset.addValue(humano, series1, (Comparable)rodada);
        dataset.addValue(zumbi, series2, (Comparable)rodada);
    }
```

and in the main

```
public Grafico g = new Grafico("Grafico");

    public void verGrafico(){
        g.atualizaDataset(qtdHumanos, qtdZumbis, nroJogada);
        g.pack();
        g.setVisible(true);
        g.repaint();
    }
```

but when i send the values to ´atualizaDataset´ he add them to the graphic but do not save this dataset to concatenate with the new values that are coming..

Comment: You could always call `setValue` on the `DefaultCategoryDataset`. But maybe you should add further information. Did you deliberately choose a `CategoryDataSet`? Wouldn't a `XYSeries` be more appropriate? What kind of data do you want to display? Just something as simple as the contents of some `double[]` array or so?

Comment: Its a graphic that shows the number of humans and zombies alive by the course of plays (its a simulator, zombies kill humans sometimes) so every round that a zombie kill a human the number of humans in the graphic decrease 1.

Comment: I was reading about this XYSeries and its really interesting. But how do i update the graphic data? It looks like that the data of the graphic its pre-defined

Comment: If you can't change something after creation, you can always replace it with a new instance...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21260302/230513) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15460355/230513). If not, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your current approach.