# How JOptionPane.showInputMessage() is implemented in Java

Tags: java, swing, message, joptionpane

I need that information so I can create custom login dialog.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
     JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter username: "); 
     // This will show dialog and after 'OK' button is clicked 
     // into that dialog, it will return the input as string, right?

}
```

So, i created new class which extends JDialog it includes 2 labels, 2 text fields and 1 button, after that button is clicked i want to simulate something like JOptionPane.showInputDialog() i want to wait for user input before other code proceed.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
   LoginDialog ld=new LoginDialog();
   ld.setVisible(true);
   // When that button is clicked i want this code to continue...
   dl.getUsername();
   dl.getPassword();
}
```

Comment: People who have tried to change `JOptionPane` regularly go mad.  Use a `JDialog` instead. I don't understand the code comment.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I've edited, try now...

Comment: Make the dialog modal.  That code is still not an SSCCE.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3002830/230513).