# making a popup window with menus

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, popupwindow

I'm writing a program to simulate an ATM machine. I have the code to simulate it but it's all text. I want to put a GUI on it which I'm working on. I originally have a window that pops up at the beginning asking for the username and password. My idea is to put a JButton that when clicked a new window will pop up with the options to be selected, "check balance, deposit and withdraw". All these options will be JButtons also to perform the actions. How can I create a new panel to appear on the screen with the options. JOptionPane.showInputDialog only displays a message. Would it be necessary to make a new JPanel for the option?
Kindly advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not wish to shove a bunch of windows at the user since that will make for a very annoying user interface. Instead, consider doing what professional applications do -- keep one window in view for the most part, but change views in that window, showing an occasional dialog window as needed. In Swing you can use a CardLayout to help you swap JPanels, each with its own GUI/view on it.

If you're interested in pursuing this, then check out the [CardLayout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). There are also plenty of examples of CardLayout use to be found on this site, several written by me.

Answer (score 1):

`JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` *only displays a message.*

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3002830/230513), the `message` can contain a number of components.

[image]