# Open a JOptionPane by another JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I am using a JOptionPane to get a string. By klicking "OK" the string is saved. Now i want the second JOptionPane to pop-up to enter the second necassary string. Is there any opportunity to add an ActionListener to the "Ok"-button from the first JOptionPane? Or what is the best solution of my problem? 
I also checked the docs, but did not found something useful yet.

My JOptionPanes lool nearly similar.

Comment: you can write your own. or, you can just call the two panes right after each other. I don't really see the problem there?

Comment: Could you show us a code example?

Comment: You can also have multiple components, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3002830/230513).

Comment: Well. I guess i am just too tired this morning. The first and the third solution are easy and totally doable. Thanks so far for the fast help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way for me is just combining it with Confirmation Dialog !

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ConfirmDialog
 {
    public static void main (String args []){


    int choose= JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Open Dialog  ??");

    if(choose== JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You Clicked Yes !!");
    } else if(choose== JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You Clicked NO");
    }
        }
         }
```