# Flexible Swing Input Dialog

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, user-input

I want to create a dialog box that consists of one column of field titles and another column of fields. I want to be able to specify the fields to only allow specific types of data. Using swing, what is the most idiomatic way of creating a reusable class for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shown in [*Validating Input*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification), you can use an `InputVerifier` to restrict input; a complete example is examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11818080/230513). In the particular case of columnar data, a [`JTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) can choose the [editor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) based on the underlying model's data type—the value returned by `getColumnClass()`. You can let the [editor validate user-entered text](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#validtext) in your implementation of `stopCellEditing()`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7539298/230513). In either case, you can add a panel containing the input component(s) to a dialog, as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33028398/230513).

[image]