# How to create JDialog with 3 sliders and 2 drop lists?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jdialog

I have an existing frame with 2 panels on it.
When the user presses one of the JButtons found on the JPanel, I need to handle the event by opening a JDialog box that allows the user to set settings - settings that include 3 sliders and 2 drop lists, when the user saves the settings I need to pull them from this dialog and use them later.
I'm new to GUI and for the past 2 and a half days I have searched for many ways to create this such of thing, and I have succeeded to make a slider and a drop list each one by its own, but I still haven't figured out how to handle an event while a frame is open, because from what I have seen I need a new JFrame, but what happens to the one alrady open? In addition, how can I make this dialog with these sliders and drop lists?

Here is the code I wrote for the slider:

```
public void setSlider()
{
    optionPane = new JOptionPane();
    JSlider slider = getSlider(optionPane);
    JSlider slider2=getSlider(optionPane);
    optionPane.setMessage(new Object[] { "Select animal's speed: ", slider });
    optionPane.setMessageType(JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    optionPane.setOptionType(JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    dialog = optionPane.createDialog(Frame, "Set speed");
    dialog.pack();
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    int speed = (int) optionPane.getInputValue();

}

static JSlider getSlider(final JOptionPane optionPane) {
    JSlider slider = new JSlider();
    slider.setMajorTickSpacing(1);
    slider.setMaximum(10);
    slider.setPaintTicks(true);
    slider.setPaintLabels(true);
    ChangeListener changeListener = new ChangeListener() {
      public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent changeEvent) {
        JSlider theSlider = (JSlider) changeEvent.getSource();
        if (!theSlider.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
          optionPane.setInputValue(new Integer(theSlider.getValue()));
        }
      }
    };
    slider.addChangeListener(changeListener);
    return slider;
  }
```

I hope this post is specified enough.
Thanks!!!

Comment: Your listener(s) can access the component values while the dialog is open or after it is closed, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3002830/230513). Which do you want?

Comment: only after it closes so it will be final

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want the dialog's results "only after it closes," simply collect the results at that time. Starting from this complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3002830/230513), the following update produces the output and appearance shown:

```
…
JSlider slider = new JSlider();
panel.add(slider);
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, "Test",
    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
    System.out.println(combo.getSelectedItem()
        + " " + field1.getText()
        + " " + field2.getText()
        + " " + slider.getValue());
} else {
…
```

```
One 1234.56 9876.54 50
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Simpler then I thought.