# How do you find the average of three numbers with input and output dialog boxes with JAVA?

Tags: java

I've been playing around with this code for a little bit now and can't seem to find the correct way to sort it out. I used a program without JOptionPane and it worked and tried to use the same sequence but it didn't work. Do I need to add something else? The assignment is to have the user enter 3 integers and print the average with input and output dialog boxes. I've done the average and input/output dialog boxes before but putting it all together is harder than I thought.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class Number3
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println("Enter 3 numbers: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00##");

    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;
    double avg;

    num1=input.nextInt();
    num2=input.nextInt();
    num3=input.nextInt();

    avg=(double)(num1+num2+num3)/3.0;
    System.out.println("The average is: " + decimalFormat.format(avg));

  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*Simple popup java form with at least two fields*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3002787/230513).

Comment: I didn’t get it, sorry. Is your program working as it stands, and you want to use `JOptionPane` instead? Or was it the other way around? Never write “it didn’t work” in a Stack Overflow question. Instead tell us precisely how the program behaved differently from the expected. Quote any error message verbatim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you find hard here. I think you are looking for this:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00##");
int num1;
int num2;
int num3;
double avg;

num1= Integer.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter #1"));
num2= Integer.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter #2"));
num3= Integer.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter #3"));

avg=(double)(num1+num2+num3)/3.0;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "The average is: " + decimalFormat.format(avg));
```

Please note that this code could be written better but for the sake of answering I just replaced the JOptionPane in your code where you need them.

Answer (score 1):

It's really not that much harder.  On the input side, using one of the `showInputDialog(...)` methods of `JOptionPane` is almost an exact replacement for `input.nextInt();`.  The only difference it that `showInputDialog(...)` returns the user's input as `String`, not an `int`, so you'll have to use `Integer.parseInt` to convert the returned `String` into an `int`.  As for the output, `showMessageDialog(...)` is an almost exact replacement for `System.out.println(...)`; just use the `---` as the message text argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num, count=0;
    double total =0, avg;

    for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
        num = Integer.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number "+ count++));
        total += num;
    }

    avg = total / count;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "The average is: " + (double)Math.round(avg * 100) / 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    /*
    *AverageOfThreeNumnber.java
    *calculating the Average Of Four Numnberand diaply the output
    *using JOptionpane method in java
    */
    import javax.swing.JOptionpane;
    public class AverageOfThreeNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
     int fristNumber; // FRIST INTEGER NUMBER
     int SecondNumber; // SECOND INTEGER NUMBER
     int ThridNumber; // THRID INTEGER NUMBER
     
     int sum; // SUM OF THE FOUR INTEGER NUMBERS
     double avarage; // AVERAGE OF THE FOUR NUMBERS

     String input; // INPUT VALUE
     String result; // OUTPUT GENERATING STRING

    // ACCEPT INTEGER NUMBERS FROM THE USER
  

    input = JOptionpane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter frist nmuber: ");
      FristNumber=Integer.parse.Int(Input);
    
      input = JOptionpane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Second nmuber: ");
      SecondNumberr=Integer.parse.Int(Input);

  

      input = JOptionpane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Thrid nmuber: ");
      ThridNumber=Integer.parse.Int(Input);
    
        
     
    //CALCULATE SUM
  sum = fristNumber + SecondNumber + ThridNumber;

    //CALCULATE AVERAGE
  average = sum/4.0

    //BUILD OUTPUT STRING AND DISPLAY OUTPUT
  result = "Average of" + fristNumber + ", " + SecondNumber + " And " + ThridNumber +" is = " + average;

    JOptionpane.showMessageDialog(null, result, "Average of 3 Numbers", JOptionpane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    
 }
}
```