# JComboBox looks old on macOS

Tags: java, macos, swing, jcombobox, look-and-feel

I have a `JComboBox` that is declared with:

```
JComboBox<String> toneList = new JComboBox<>(tones); //tones is a String[] list
```

And is added with:

```
panel.add(toneList);
window.add(panel);
```

But the issue is that it looks old and just generally looks bad. This is what it currently looks like.

[image]

I want it to look like this, which looks more modern.

[image]

Is there a Look and Feel that achieves this or is the second one actually something else?

Answer (score 2):

Your second screenshot looks like a `JComboBox` with a smaller font than the `UIManager` default of 13 points. Starting from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3002830/230513), you can change the size like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    UIManager.put("ComboBox.font", new JComboBox().getFont().deriveFont(12f));
    …
}
```

[image]